# Tkinter and threading to control continuous background process

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading

I want to use Tkinter to interact with another thread. The output (assuming the user clicks the button after two seconds) should be:

```
Steve
Steve
Joline
Joline
Joline
```

Where am I going wrong?

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import threading
from threading import Thread


def changeName():
    person = "Joline"


def controls():
    root = Tk()
    button = Button(text="Change Name", command=changeName)
    button.pack(side=LEFT)
    root.mainloop()


def work():
    person = "Steve"
    for _ in range(5):
        print("hello " + person)
        time.sleep(1)


Thread(target = controls).start()
Thread(target = work).start()
```

Comment: Don't use threads like this with Tk...

Comment: Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: Yes, I'll post an answer in a few moments.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to make the "person" variable global. Here is what I should have done to get the desired result:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import threading
from threading import Thread

person = ""

def changeName():
    global person
    person = "Sonia"


def controls():
    root = Tk()
    button = Button(text="Change Name", command=changeName)
    button.pack(side=LEFT)
    root.mainloop()


def work():
    for _ in range(10):
        print("hello " + person)
        time.sleep(1)


Thread(target = controls).start()
Thread(target = work).start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Your `name` variables are never changed because they are *local* to the respective functions they are in. This is a bad approach even if it does work. Tkinter is already one giant thread loop (what do you think `mainloop` is doing, it's looping checking for events in the queue to process) you shouldn't be putting it inside another loop and we can use built-in methods to achieve this.

Just for kicks I imported string and random to create random strings so you could see it working.

The `changeName` function could use sleep but we already have tkinter imported and it already has built-in functionality / event queue so why not use it...

I just added the name as an attribute to the Tk class rather than having to worry about globals, locals, etc.

```
import tkinter as tk, string, random

root = tk.Tk()
root.name = "a name"

def changeName(shouldRun=False):

    if not shouldRun:
        root.after(2000, changeName, True)
    else:
        root.name = "".join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(10)])

def printName():

    print(root.name)
    root.after(1000, printName)

btn = tk.Button(root, text="Change Name", command=changeName)
btn.pack()
printName()
root.mainloop()
```